# How to load the same row twice and avoid hibernate exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to load some data from an outside source. I am getting the data then using hibernate to create the objects then add everything to my database.

In one case I have two entity classes which are related to each other.
Item.java and service.java. It is possible to have the same service associated with an item twice but with a different price. In the database this would be three table

1. Item
2. Service
3. vice (item_id, service_id, price)

the objects would be

**Item.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

// Other attributes

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ItemService> itemServices = new HashSet<ItemService>();
```

**ItemService.java**

```
@EmbeddedId
    private ItemServicePK id = new ItemServicePK();

    @Column(name = "price")
    private String price;

    // Other attributes
```

When I am importing the data I am creating and saving the service objects to the DB. Then I create the item objects and associate the appropriate service to the item.
This is the code which does that:

```
//Create item object

Item item = new Item();
item.setId((Long) jsonObj.get("id"));

//Add the services

for(int x = 0; x < service.size(); x++) {
   JSONObject serviceObj = (JSONObject) services.get(x);
   Service service = serviceDAO.getServiceById(Long.valueOf(serviceObj.get("service_id").toString()));
   ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
   itemService.setItem(item);
   itemService.setService(service);
   itemService.setPrice(serviceObj.get("price").toString());
   item.getItemServices().add(itemService);
}
```

This is how I am retreiving the service:

```
@Transactional
    public Service getServiceById(Long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (Service) session.load(Service.class, new Long(id));
    }
```

I add the items to the database using:

```
Session session = getSession();
    for(Item item : items) {
        session.saveOrUpdate(item);
    }
```

The problem is I get an Exception `saying an object with the same identifier is in the session`. I know that this is because sometimes I have two Services which have the same Id being associated to the Item but at a different price. I have tried using session.merge instead but this causes a `Java.lang.StackOverflow` exception.

Is there any way to overcome this. For example instead of getting the same object twice using the DAO could I check if it exists in the session and retrieve that object instead?

Any other solution would aslo be welcome.

Comment: Try doing a session.load(id) this returns object ref if exists inside the Session. You can use this object to update the object and then call session.merge.

Comment: It's really confusing what you are asking. Could you please elaborate why would you have entities with the SAME id but having different values in them? This seems to be just an update operation on the original entity.

Comment: @galovics. I am doing that. Please see my updated question